# Are functions of this sort bijections from a subset of the reals to the reals?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, functions

I'm teaching about infinite cardinalities tomorrow and will be showing that $\tan x$ is a bijection from $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  As I was putting the slides together, it occurred to me that there are probably *lots* of bijections from subsets of reals to reals, and started thinking about why $\tan x$ worked.

Suppose you have a function $f : (a, b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the following properties is a bijection:

- $f$ is continuous on $(a, b)$.
- $f$ is monotonically increasing on $(a, b)$.
- $\lim_{x \rightarrow a+} f(x) = -\infty$.
- $\lim_{x \rightarrow b-} f(x) = +\infty$.

I have a background in discrete math rather than continuous mathematics, so I'm not exactly sure how I would prove this.  I can prove that the function is injective because it's monotonically increasing, but I'm not sure how to prove surjectivity from the other claims.

My questions are as follows:

- Am I right?  That is, is my guess correct?
- If I'm right, how would I prove surjectivity from these points?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want another example that is easy to prove works algebraically, take $\dfrac{x}{1-x^2}$ on $(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a function with those properties will be a bijection. It's $1-1$ if we assume that it is *strictly* monotone, and the [intermediate value theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntermediateValueTheorem.html) shows that it's onto as follows:

Choose an $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $\lim_{x \to b^+} f(x) = \infty$, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that

$$b - \epsilon < y < b \implies f(y) > \alpha$$

Likewise, there exists an $\epsilon'$ for the left side. Choosing any $y$ and $z$ in the two respective intervals, we see that some $c \in [y, z]$ must satisfy $f(c) = \alpha$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you’re right. You can use the intermediate value theorem from first-year calculus to show that $f$ must map $(a,b)$ onto $\Bbb R$. Specifically, let $y\in\Bbb R$ be arbitrary. The limit conditions ensure that there are $c,d\in(a,b)$ such that $f(c)<y<f(d)$, the (strict) monotonicity ensures that $c<d$, and you can now apply the intermediate value theorem to the interval $[c,d]$ to get an $x\in[c,d]\subseteq(a,b)$ such that $f(x)=y$.